# How to display category image in home page with custom css?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, ce-1.9.2.4

I want to display all of my category image with in home page. What should i do for this?
I am using CE:1.9.2.4

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. The "with custom CSS" part of your question is confusing. What exactly do you need to know? How to add custom CSS to the home page? How to create a template for the home page? How to load categories? Please be more specific and explain what you already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of such a code:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854739/how-to-show-category-images-in-cms-page-in-magento

Another option would be a widget or block, please see this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787545/magento-display-category-image-by-id-in-cms-page

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
$_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories();

$cats = array();

function getCats($_categories)
{
    global $cats;
    foreach ($_categories as $_category) {
        if($_category->getIsActive()) {         
            echo "url ->".$_category->getUrl()."<br>";
            echo "name->".$_category->getName()."<br>";
            echo "id->".$_category->getId()."<br>";
            $childCats = $_category->getChildrenCategories();
            if (count($childCats) > 0) getLowestCats($childCats);
        }
    }
}
getCats($_categories);
```